# Комментарии к записи вк api

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Через java в коментарий к посту пытаюсь прикреплять ссылку, смотрю на метод
https://vk.com/dev/wall.addComment
но там в поле attachments нету поля для прикрепления ссылки, только фото и тд.
Если брать ссылку и закидывать в параметр text, то тогда будет просто ссылка строкой
Мне же нужно чтобы подгружалась картинка с сайта вместе с сылкой

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/attachments_w - наиболее актуальное описание медиавложений, применимое в том числе и для комментариев.  На странице https://vk.com/dev/wall.addComment просто ленятся обновлять документацию по этому полю.

Comment: А вообще, в качестве документации лучше всего использовать исходный код [официальных SDK](https://vk.com/dev/SDK) - они гораздо чаще обновляются, нежели документация

Comment: @SergeyRufanov , тогда мне нужен обьект link, у него есть поля url, title,description и тд
подскажите пожалуйста
Они должны быть в формате attachments=link_url_title_description
или как?